# ES6. Webpack. Именованный (частичный) импорт

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

**дано:**

библиотека 'partial-export' вида

```
// src/index.js
export const foo = () => 'foo'
export const bar = () => 'bar'
```

собирается вебпаком в бандл

приложение 'partial-import' в котором библиотека 'partial-export' установлена через npm как зависимость

доступ к функциям возможен -

```
import * as partial from "partial-export"; // size ~20Kb

console.log(partial.foo()) // -> 'foo'
```

или

```
import { bar } from "partial-export"; // size ~20Kb

console.log(bar()) // -> 'bar'
```

и в том и в другом случае библиотека загружается полность хотя используется только часть функциональности.

**вопрос:**
как добится следуещей функциональности при которой будет грузится только часть библиотеки?

```
import foo from "partial-export/foo"; // size ~10Kb
console.log(foo()) // -> 'foo'
```

Comment: Так у вас и грузится только часть библиотеки partial-export, разве нет? Посмотрите непожатый код бандла на присутствие неимпортированных функций или дополните вопрос конфигураций webpack.

Comment: 'function(e,t,r){"use strict";r.r(t),r.d(t,"foo",function(){return n}),r.d(t,"bar",function(){return o});const n=()=>"foo",o=()=>"bar"}'
вот кусок бандла где видно что втягиваются обефункции

Comment: то чего вы хотите добиться называется tree shaking, чтобы этого добиться нужно разбить пакет на submodules, то есть функция `foo` в файле `foo.js` и так же с bar, так же сделано и в лодеше, все функции в разных файлах, благодаря этому можно не грузить весь пакет целиком

Comment: @overthesanity вы ошибаетесь. Внимательно прочитайте ещё раз раздел Tree Shaking. Там обе функции живут в math.js и в конце написаны простые шаги, которые надо выполнить, чтобы заработал tree shaking: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, перечитайте вопрос, который задал человек еще раз, как по вашему те шаги помогут добиться такого импорта `partial-export/foo`?

Comment: Ответом на вопрос "как добится следуещей функциональности при которой будет грузится только часть библиотеки" будет: "сделайте так, как написано в главе Tree Shaking".

Comment: нет не будет. потому как библиотека сначала загрузится вся а потом обрежется вебпаком... или не обрежется https://habr.com/company/wrike/blog/342686/
А меня интересует как добится того чтобы на этапе импорта грузилась только та часть которая указывается

Comment: @torokhkun, тут вы правы, поэтому команда лодеш приняла такое дизайн решение (это я вам просто как пример привожу)